# Unity object respawn keeps it moving

Tags: object, unity-game-engine

My object and it's clones(with a collider attached) are pooled and deactivated on swipe left or right. When they are activated, they immediateliy move along the direction of swipe. How can possibly set their respawn speed to zero?(horizontal movement)

Comment: So....... The objects are moving until you swipe left (deactivating them), and then when you swipe right (re-activating them), they continue the previous movement tendencies ?

Comment: Well, what controls their speed? If it's a rigidbody, you could set its velocity to zero upon respawn.

Comment: @Zze swiping the swiped object in the counter direction makes it move at the same speed in the counter direction.

Comment: @rutter transform.translate in update function makes it move. By the way a collider is attached to the object but i coudn't make it stop the movement by it. No rigidboy. Thank you both for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a script for the objects I wouldn't want to move and either attach it to each individual object or a manager based object which controls the spawned objects. You can simply after instantiating, set their speed variable to 0 and call a coroutine for x seconds and at the end of the coroutine it would change their speed variable back. Make sure each has its own variable for speed as to not affect the whole lot.

It would be something like this..

```
GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
// set speed to zero here.
StartCoroutine(WaitAndMove(2.0F));
```

And add this function

```
IEnumerator WaitAndMove(float waitTime) {
yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
// set speed back here 
}
```

Comment: I see... But i rather use object pooling than instantiating my objects which means i deactivate swiped objects, not destroy them. That's why i can not set their speed to zero as you suggest because i don't instantiate swiped objecst. I just activate them. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It depends on your method for pooling. As far as I understand. Pooling is just re-using several already instantiated objects. Usually pooling systems de-activate and re-activate per use. Well if you put my logic (subtract the instantiate part) within the wake method of your object. It should work out all the same lol.